# Can't get socket.io on client side

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I'm having a hard time to access socket.io on the client side.
While searching for the problem I found the following notations:

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/socket-lib/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.jss"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:80/socket.io/socket.io.jss"></script>
```

None of those seems to do the trick. When I call the following in my client HTML file

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

I always get the error:

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined [Break On This Error] var socket =
io.connect('http://localhost');
```

Shouldn't this work "automagically"?

PS: Here's what my server side Script looks like:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/temp.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading temp.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
});
```

Comment: Check your browser console. Is the browser actually loading a JavaScript file from that URI?

Comment: you wrote "/socket.io/socket.io.jss" instead of .js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG! Copy&Paste struck again. Thanks!